# Copiar determinada parte de uma String com uma referência

Tags: java

Quero copiar uma determinada parte de uma String com uma referência.
Ex `*111111111**22222222**333333*`
Como faço para copiar oque está dentro dos `* *` em java

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2):

Olha não sei se o teu objetivo é pegar uma das partes da string ou o texto todo da mesma, então aqui vai duas soluções:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String texto = "*111111111**22222222**333333*";
    String txt = "";
    for(String text : texto.split("\\*"))
    {
        txt += text;
    }
    
    // Pega a string inteira, todos os registros entre os *
    System.out.println(txt);
    
    // Pega só um dos itens entre os * (lembrando que ** significa um texto vazil)
    System.out.println(texto.split("\\*")[3]);
}
```

Retorno:

```
11111111122222222333333
22222222
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).